# Laravel 5 hasManyThrough error

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, has-many-through

I’m learning a lot about these eloquent relationships but I’m not quite there in my understanding.

I have three tables:

**Candidates**
•   id
•   candidate_number
•   givennames
•   familyname
•   dob 
•   created_at
•   updated_at

**Results**
•   id
•   certificate_number
•   candidate_id
•   qualification_id
•   created_at
•   updated_at

**Qualifications**
•   id
•   code
•   title
•   created_at
•   updated_at

A candidate has many results and a qualification has many results. A result belongs to a qualification and a candidate.  On the candidaes.show page I want to show what qualifications are related to that candidate using a hasManyThrogh relationship. 
Here are my models.

**Candidates:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model {

    protected $table = 'candidates';
    public $timestamps = true;


    public function result()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
    }

    public function qualification()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Qualification', 'App\Result');
    }
}
```

**Result Model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Result extends Model {

   protected $table = 'results';
   public $timestamps = true;

   public function candidate()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Candidate');
   }

   public function qualification()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Qualification');
   }

}
```

**Qualification Model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Qualification extends Model {

   protected $table = 'qualifications';
   public $timestamps = true;

   public function result()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
   }

   public function candidate()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Candidate', 'App\Result');
   }
}
```

**In my candidate controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $candidate = Candidate::with('qualification')->find($id);

    return view('candidates.show', compact('candidate'));
}
```

**and in my view:**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    <h1>{{ $candidate->givennames }} {{ $candidate->familyname }}</h1>

    <div class="body"> {{ $candidate->dob }} </div>

    <div class="body"> {{ $candidate->candidate_number }} </div>

    <h3> Centre </h3>


    <h3> Qualifications </h3>

    @foreach($candidate->qualification as $qualification)

        <div class="body"> {{ $qualification->title }} </div>

    @endforeach

@stop
```

However it is retuning the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'qualifications.result_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `qualifications`.*, `results`.`candidate_id` from `qualifications` inner join `results` on `results`.`id` = `qualifications`.`result_id` where `results`.`candidate_id` in (17))

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction? I’m not even sure I am doing the right thing with a hasManyThrough.

Answer (score 0):

If a result has many Qualifications then a foreign key needs to be placed on the Qualification Table. Like so:

```
$table->integer('result_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('result_id')->references('id')->on('results');
```

You don't need to delete the table to add this. Just go to your terminal and create a new migration file

```
php artisan make:migration edit_qualification_table --table=qualifications
```

Then add these within the up function. Same with down so if you do delete the table these will be deleted too.

Comment: Sorry not sure if I’m explaining myself well. A result only has one qualification. At least that’s what I’m trying to do.